# fulfillment of orders via shopify API

Tags: php, api, shopify, fulfillment

i have a test shop on shopify. When the orders are created I want to update their fulfilment status to "Fulfilled" via PHP API calls.

So far nothing is mentioned in the documentation to update the fulfilment status of the line items in the order.

Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. API Fulfillment is possible: http://api.shopify.com/fulfillment.html

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have it working now

```
$data = array( "fulfillment" => array("tracking_number" => "1111111111"));

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$ch = curl_init('https://API:PASS@STORE.myshopify.com/admin/orders/ORDER_ID/fulfillments.json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Wow I've spent two days on this and posted on this site and Shopify forums and could not for the life of me get remote fulfillment to work, and your code did it! Thank you. Much better than the Shopify Dev docs. Just need to include the location_id in the JSON.